# NODE_ENV changed for cloud run services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I had multiple nodejs services deployed on Cloud Run. The value of `NODE_ENV` was `production` initially. However, it suddenly changed to `development` for all the services.

1. What could be the reason for this?
2. How can I revert the value back to `production`?

Attaching the log screenshot from one of the services.
[image]

Some additional info if it might help :

1. The services are using Nest.js
2. I am not setting the `NODE_ENV` variable during deployment

Comment: The log entries mention `loading db creds`. What does that actually mean? Is ENV being changed by a file your code is downloading?

Comment: I was just printing the value of NODE_ENV.  
```logger.info(`loading db creds. ENV is ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)```

Comment: You are setting `NODE_ENV` somewhere. There is no magic to that. Search the code, configuration, etc, and find where it is getting set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had similar issue. I tried to re-deploy cloud functions from our pipeline from the previous week using updated env variables. The deployment was successful on previous week and now it failed. We use `latest` as the `google/cloud-sdk` version.

Found this link and was able to fix the deployment: https://pullanswer.com/questions/dont-set-google_experimental_nodejs_npm_build_enabled-by-default

Google Cloud Build now sets `GOOGLE_EXPERIMENTAL_NODEJS_NPM_BUILD_ENABLED=true` as default and that triggers the NPM build automatically. Also `NODE_ENV` changed from `production` to `development` as a side effect. Adding GCP script to `package.json` didn't help as the deployment was still run as `development`. Cloud Build installs dev dependencies and then prunes those later. To get similar results as before, we had to set these environment variables to the cloud function deployment:

```
GOOGLE_NODE_RUN_SCRIPTS: ''
NODE_ENV: 'production'
```